# Como não exibir registros de datas passadas

Tags: php, mysql

Eu fiz uma agenda e preciso que eventos que já passaram não apareçam mais, as datas estão com 3 campos DIA/MES/ANO, estou usando o concat e date para juntar e formatar as datas, então fica assim a query atual:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `tabela1` WHERE `evento` LIKE '%$busca%' ORDER BY date(concat(ano,'-', mes,'-',dia)) ASC") or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM `tabela1`
WHERE `evento` LIKE '%$busca%'
AND `nomeDoCampoData` > '2014-04-10'
ORDER BY date(concat(ano,'-', mes,'-',dia)) ASC
```

Se quiser pegar entre um período utilize o `between`

```
SELECT *
FROM `tabela1` 
WHERE `evento` LIKE '%$busca%'
AND `nomeDoCampoData` BETWEEN '2014-04-10' AND '2014-04-13'
ORDER BY `nomeDoCampoData`
```

Dica não utilize um campo para cada um: data, mes, ano... Utilize apenas um campo do tipo `DATE`

Comment: valew, peguei o código q vc acabou de postar e fiz umas modificações!!! tá no tópico editada...